# Combine 2 rows into 1 row using 3 columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the following structure into one row:

```
ID     SubID    Total1  Total2  Total3
-----  -------  ------  ------  ------
Apple  Fruit    12      null    12
Apple  Veggies  null    24      24
```

And this is my desired result:

```
ID     FruitTotal  VeggieTotal  TotalTotal
-----  ----------  -----------  ----------  
Apple  12          24           36
```

Comment: Sorry now I don't get how Total1, Total2, and Total3 come together in your final result.

Comment: Do you know you only want fruit and veggie totals, or do you need the query to dynamically figure out that there may be other SubID types?

Comment: An apple is a fruit or a veggie???????

Comment: Can you show us what you mean, because still the only thing I can extrapolate is you want to add the columns vertically. Otherwise you would have 24 fruit, 48 veggies, and 72 total.

Comment: @lc. I think the `Total3` column is just a redundant copy of `Total1` *or* `Total2`, not a separate total of its own.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think you're quite right, but as long as that column exists, the best answer would be to sum the columns vertically, no?

Comment: @lc. yes, or you could just ignore that column. You can get the desired results in either way (I was merely commenting because I didn't believe there was any logic that led to 24/48/72).

Comment: Does he want to PIVOT on SubID to get the two total column values WHERE ID = Apple? Then TotalTotal is those 'Pivoted' columns combined?

Comment: @AaronBertrand My answer suggested to sum the columns, but the OP commented that it there was more to the question. Not knowing how Total1, Total2, and Total3 figure into the picture the only other options are to sum all the totals together (getting 24/48/72) or to selectively ignore columns. Of course 24/48/72 is wrong, but since the OP is not providing any additional info, we're just left to guess.

Comment: @lc. but given the desired results, I'm suggesting that that specific approach doesn't seem to match the OP's requirements.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, that's actually my point, although I'm clearly not very eloquent right now - feel free to ignore me if I'm not making sense. I was just trying to demonstrate that the OP needs to give us more insight into how they arrived at the result if adding the columns vertically is not the proper method.

Comment: @lc. I think the only real problem is that he wants the columns named according to the SubID (which means it's unlikely to be vertical except by coincidence, but I still think the total3 column is redundant and can be ignored when getting the results). Too bad he's gone silent and is letting us chew on our assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Id AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @Id = 'Apple'

IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT ID,
           SUM(ISNULL(Total1,0)) AS Total1,
           SUM(ISNULL(Total2,0)) AS Total2,
           SUM(ISNULL(Total3,0)) AS Total3
    FROM   Table
    GROUP BY ID
END
ELSE
    SELECT ID,
           SUM(ISNULL(Total1,0)) AS Total1,
           SUM(ISNULL(Total2,0)) AS Total2,
           SUM(ISNULL(Total3,0)) AS Total3
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  ID = @Id
    GROUP BY ID
BEGIN
END
```

**EDIT**

You may need this instead

```
DECLARE @Id AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @Id = 'Apple'

IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT ID,
           (SELECT SUM(Total1) FROM Table WHERE ID = T.ID AND SubId = 'Fruit') AS FruitTotal,
           (SELECT SUM(Total2) FROM Table WHERE ID = T.ID AND SubId = 'Veggies') AS VeggiesTotal
           SUM(ISNULL(Total3,0)) AS Total3
    FROM   Table T
    GROUP BY ID
END
ELSE
    SELECT ID,
           (SELECT SUM(Total1) FROM Table WHERE ID = T.ID AND SubId = 'Fruit') AS FruitTotal,
           (SELECT SUM(Total2) FROM Table WHERE ID = T.ID AND SubId = 'Veggies') AS VeggiesTotal
           SUM(ISNULL(Total3,0)) AS Total3
    FROM   Table T
    WHERE  ID = @Id
    GROUP BY ID
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: +1 Although possibly add a WHERE clause if he wants 'Apples' specifically. WHERE id = 'Apple'.

Comment: @Clev231 I added a variable. If set to NULL then get them all, else get the Id of the variable

Comment: I've fixed your syntax and changed the comparison to use the variable as you surely intended

Comment: The predicate ID = @ ID OR @ ID IS NULL is likely to prevent an index seek.  It would be better to execute the exact statement.  Either make the parameter non-nullable, or use control flow to take a different path if the parameter is null.

Comment: @AdamHaines Edited to fit your comment. Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to branch like that, I'd rather use dynamic SQL. You lose a little bit in terms of readability, but at least if you have to change the query, you only change it in one spot. Now imagine there is just one additional optional parameter, how much more complex this branching becomes. Now think about 10 independently optional parameters.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I feel you, but what would you suggest instead?

Comment: I'm just suggesting that it can be done with dynamic SQL also. This is the definition of scope creep (the OP never said there was a parameter or that it was optional), so I don't suggest investing a lot of time or thought into it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need three `SUM`s:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Total1), SUM(Total2), SUM(Total3)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7cb16/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   ID,
         SUM(Total1),
         SUM(Total2),
         SUM(Total3)
FROM     FruitTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Take a look at [Aggregate Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) in SQL and [SUM function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
    sum(coalesce(total1,0)) as Total1, 
  sum(coalesce(total2,0)) as Total2, 
  sum(coalesce(total3,0))  as Total3
from t
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to what you've already seen - but there's no aggregate for summing across *columns* in a single row. So you just need to do the maths manually:

```
select
    ID,
    SUM(COALESCE(Total1,0)) as FruitTotal,
    SUM(COALESCE(Total2,0)) as VeggieTotal,
    SUM(COALESCE(Total1,0) + COALESCE(Total2,0)) as TotalTotal
from
    [Table]
group by ID
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to add the first two columns. He just wants to add the rows grouped by id (excluding SubId)

Comment: @jyparask - the OPs third column (after much editing) is now called `TotalTotal`, and throughout the examples, it's always matched the sum of the other columns, which is why I thought this might be what they're after.